# Slide next content when <input> slides right and slides left when <input> hides

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a menu that has 'Search', 'Filter' and 'Sort'. A < input > should slide right when 'Search' is clicked showing the text field. When 'Search' is clicked again, the < input > should now hide. The < span > next to it should also move right giving < input > a space and move left when  is hidden.

The < input > don't behave as it should the same with the < span > next to it,
The < input > should only show when the user click 'Search'.
HTML

```
<div class="header">
        <span class="search">Search</span>
        <input class="_input"/>
        <span class="tool">Filter</span>
        <span class="tool">Sort</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```
input {
}

_input{

}

.tool{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

JS

```
$( ".search" ).click(function() {
  $( "._input" ).toggle( "slide" );
});
```

[Here the JSFiddle for reference.](http://jsfiddle.net/Holmes/odj09uw6/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this : give `style="float:left;"` for each `span`, add `div` with `style="clear:both;"` at the end using css classes.

add following CSS classes -

```
.floatLeft {float:left;}

.clear {clear:both;}

._input{
 display:none;
 margin-left:5px;   
}

.tool{
    position: relative;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

modify html -

```
<div class="header">
    <span class="search floatLeft">Search</span>
    <input class="_input floatLeft" />
    <span class="tool floatLeft">Filter</span>
    <span class="tool floatLeft">Sort</span>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/kawadkarbk31/odj09uw6/14/)**

Comment: That's works! But the textfield should be hidden the first time the page loads. It should only be shown when the user clicked 'Search'...

Comment: please check my updated answer, I have added css classes. `._input` css is to hide `input` on page load.

Comment: That solves my problem! Thank you, Bhushan Kawadkar. But, is there a way to animate it smothly? I mean, when the textfield slides right, the Filter and Sort also slides at the same time, vice versa.

Comment: yeah there should be a way but I am not aware of it. I tried to make smooth animation as you said but no use. sorry for that.